# using pandas.DataFrame.idxmax and wanting to using a joint argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Each row in the image represents a baseball game. Trying to getting the idxmax method to return a different word or number to show when they're is a joint maximum in the columns

[image: Each row in the image represents a baseball game. Trying to getting the idxmax method to return a different word or number to show when they're is a joint maximum in the columns]

This is the code I've used to get the inning which has the most runs. It returns the index with the first maximum and I'm trying to find a way to show something in the output that shows a joint maximum (i.e. two or more innings that have the maximum amount of runs scored):

````
df['maxInningsRuns'] = sbr[['1ITotRuns','2ITotRuns','3ITotRuns','4ITotRuns','5ITotRuns','6ITotRuns','7ITotRuns','8ITotRuns','9ITotRuns','XITotRuns']].idxmax(axis=1)```
````

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you post a link to an image instead of trying to format the table inside the question

Answer (score 1):

Do no post pictures of the code. Actually give code that people can use since you are new, and this was relatively easy to do, I did that below, so follow that in the future in creating/providing some sample of the dataset).

Get the value of that and use that to slice your dataframe. Or just iterate through each column list to see if the value is in there. There are multiple ways to do it.

```
import pandas as pd

rows = [[3,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,1,0],
        [0,0,1,1,0,0,5,2,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [2,0,1,1,1,1,2,0,2,0],
        [0,0,0,4,5,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,1,4,1,0,0,0]]



cols = ['1ITotRuns','2ITotRuns',
        '3ITotRuns','4ITotRuns',
        '5ITotRuns','6ITotRuns',
        '7ITotRuns','8ITotRuns',
        '9ITotRuns','XITotRuns']

sbr = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = cols)

# Returns the max values of each inning
max_each_column = sbr[cols].max()

# Gets 1 column where that max value is found
idx_max_value = sbr[cols].max().idxmax()

# Use the column the get that value (5)
max_value = sbr[idx_max_value].max()

#Find columns that have 5 in it
max_innings = [col for col in cols if max_value in list(sbr[col])]
print(max_innings)
```

**Output:**

```
['5ITotRuns', '7ITotRuns']
```